# How to include buffer-file-name in completing-read

Tags: completing-read

I can use completing-read to choose from several items like this:

```
(completing-read
 "Complete a foo: "
 '(("apple" 1) ("barfoo" 2) ("elk" 3) ("foobar2" 4)) ;; collection of choices
 nil t )
```

But the example below does not show the value of buffer-file-name as one of the choices:

```
(completing-read
 "Complete a foo: "
 '(((buffer-file-name) 1) ("barfoo" 2) ("elk" 3) ("foobar2" 4)) ;; collection of choices
 nil t )
```

How can I include buffer-file-name as one of the choices?

Comment: Quoting prevents evaluation. Use backquote, not quote, and use comma for the sexp you want evaluated inside the backquoted sexp: `(buffer-file-name)`.

Comment: Translation for non-experts: Use `((( and then ,(buffer-file-name).